# How to retrieve the complete xml (DataType as XMLTYPE) from the specific column using jdbc and java-swing

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jdbc

I have an table name called student ,in that table i have one column named as student_xml and another one is student_id

so i have written the below code for retrieve the data from the db.

select student_xml  from student where student_id='2301C8';

when i execute this query in sql server its works fine but when i tried this with swing application (java database connectivity) getting the null values.

```
String strxa = tfx1.getText(); //here i will get the student id from user.

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service","username","pwd");
    Statement st =con.createStatement();
    String str3 ="select student_xml  from student where student_id='"+strxa+"'";

    System.out.println(str3);

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(str3);
    System.out.println(str3);

   if (rs.next()) {

            XMLType poxml = (XMLType)rs.getObject(1);
            System.out.println(poxml); //when i try to print this no output in console
            String poString =poxml.getStringVal();
            System.out.println(poString); when i try to print this no output in console


            //Sets Records in TextFields.
            area.setText(poString);


        }
```

Is there any other way we have to follow for the XMLTYPE data and display this things in the text area?

Comment: **What** *exactly* is null? Please clarify. This question really has little to do with Swing per se, fyi.

Comment: null means there is no value its picking so i am getting the print response as null,now updated the code as per MarrieteCowby12 answers but now i am getting the exception @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here would be the proper code to receive data from a result set that is XMLTYPE

1. add the following import -  `import oracle.xdb.XMLType;`
2. Use the following while loop, It will retrieve the XMLTYPE and store it in a string called `poString`.

   ```
    while(rs.next())
   { 
     // get the XMLType 
    XMLType poxml = (XMLType)rs.getObject(1); 

      // get the XML as a string...
    String poString = poxml.getStringVal();
    }
   ```

Comment: I am getting the below exception when i execute,
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/internal/XMLTypeIntf
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: i have added xdb6 and ojdbc14 jars too same exception,i have tried to print the poxml  and poString  in console , its not getting executed /printed @MarrieteCowby12

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.internal.XMLTypeIntf Error too getting

Comment: I am marking this answer as right, because its answered correctly what i asked?

Comment: The error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError can be caused by having an incorrect classpath configuration, can you please verify that your classpath is correct?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError comes when a problematic class was present when you compiled your application but they are not in your classpath while you running your program.